# How can I make a data-dojo-attach-event run?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I am trying to run the event after adding a domNode programatically as such:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dojo-attach-event="click:openRegistration">Register</a>
```

This event is not parsed by Dojo when the page is first loaded because it is being added later on. Even after running

```
parser.parse();
```

The event does not run. How can I make this event run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the dojo parser to parse the page twice: it would redundantly parse and create things that were already created and cause a mess. To add a node programmatically after the page has been parsed, have a look at [dojo/dom-construct](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.10/dojo/dom-construct.html).

```
require(["dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(domConstruct) {

        var openRegistration = function() {
            alert("foo");
        }

        domConstruct.create("a", {
            innerHTML: "Register",
            click: openRegistration,
            href: "javascript:void(0)"
        }, document.body);
    });
```

Replace document.body with a reference to the parent node where you want to insert the node, and look at the 3rd parameter for placement options.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for

Comment: Kyle,How we can we pass some data with openRegistration function?

Comment: openRegistration will get the Dojo-normalized event as an argument. With that you can get to the node and widget which fired the event, which might be enough. If not, `dojo/_base/lang.hitch` or function.bind to bind the `this` openRegistration sees to the widget so it can retrieve whatever data it needs. `click: lang.hitch(this, openRegistration),`. Then openRegistration has access to all of the widget data. You can also pass arguments to the lang.hitch and they'll be mixed in to the call to openRegistration: the normal dojo event argument would then appear last.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `onclick:openRegistration` instead of `click:openRegistration`.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:openRegistration">Register</a>
```

Comment: It did not work. In their documentation, you can use the `click` event instead of `onclick`

Comment: dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin specifies data-dojo-attach-event="onclick" reference from documentation https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html

Comment: I tried it either ways, and it did not work. This is the reference I was mentioning:https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/events.html

I am getting this message from the server, and I am simply plugging it in which means Dojo has already rendered the page.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of you code I'm gussesin you have a scope issue. Or you haven't cased the dom event correctly -  **onClick**

You function needs to be part of the same widget that uses the templates with attach-events that inherits [_TemplatedMixin](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.htm).  You widget that's using that attach-event should look something like

```
require([
    'dojo/declare',
    'dijit/_WidgetBase', 
    'dijit/_TemplatedMixin', 
    'dojo/text!myNameSpace/templates/MyWidget.html'
], 
function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template){
    declare('MyWidget', [ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin ], {
        templateString: template, 
        openRegistration: function {
               // do stuff here
        }
    });
});
```